# Is every 3-dimensional Poincaré complex a 3-dimensional topological variety?

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, low-dimensional-topology, poincare-duality

I have this question, if every 3-dimensional Poincaré complex is a 3-dimensional topological manifold?

**Definition (Poincaré complex)**
$X$ is a n-dimensional Poincaré complex if $X$ have the same homotopy type of a finite CW complex with a homomorphism $$ w: \pi_1 (X) \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}/2 $$ and $M \in H_n (X;\mathbb{Z}[w])$, such that 
$$H^\ast (X;\mathbb{Z}[w]) \rightarrow ^{\frown [M]} H_{n-s}(X;\mathbb{Z}[w])$$ is a isomorphism.

Comment: By "any" do you mean "every"? And what is a "topological variety"? Do you mean "a topological manifold"?

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE.  Please review [ask].  Especially when asking about topics from advanced subjects, Readers will reasonably expect that you give more context about the problem you want help with.   Bare problem statements are often ambiguous as to where you found difficulty in approaching them, and in this way it can convey the impression that an assigned exercise is being "passed through" without the thought necessary to digest its meaning.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you can always modify an $n$-dimensional closed (oriented if you prefer) connected $n$-dimensional manifold to make it into a finite CW $n$-dimensional Poincare complex  which is not a manifold: Just attach a 1-cell to it along a vertex of this cell. This does not change the homotopy type, hence, keeps the space $X$ a Poincare complex, but $X$ is clearly not a manifold. Thus, a meaningful question to ask is:

> Is every $n$-dimensional finite Poincare complex homotopy-equivalent to an $n$-dimensional manifold?

In dimension 2, it is a nontrivial theorem due to Bieri, Linnell and Muller that the question has positive answer. In dimension 3 the answer is negative, an example is due to C.B. Thomas, it is somewhere in his book:

[Elliptic Structures on 3-Manifolds](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/052131576X), Cambridge University Press, 1986.

In fact, he had this example already in 1977 modulo the [Smale Conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smale_conjecture) which was proven by Hatcher in 1983.

It is a famous open problem (due to C.T.C. Wall) if every finite aspherical n-dimensional Poincare complex is homotopy equivalent to an n-dimensional manifold, $n\ge 3$. From what I know, the question is expected to have positive answer in dimension 3 and negative answer in (sufficiently) higher dimensions. Already in dimension 3 this problem is notoriously difficult.

Two more papers to read:

C.T.C Wall, [Poincare duality in dimension 3](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0410043.pdf), 2004.

J. Klein, [Poincare duality spaces](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d6f0/eae863324a9711c4dfade9023a3a9af3adef.pdf), In: *Surveys on surgery theory*, Vol. 1, 135–165, 
Ann. of Math. Stud., 145, Princeton Univ. Press, Princeton, NJ, 2000.

See also my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2076696/poincare-duality-in-group-cohomology).